# Get related Jquery submenu to stay open on new page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I need help with following [menu](http://jsfiddle.net/hNddK/23/).

How would I get a particular submenu to stay open when a submenu item is clicked and another page is loaded.

[Code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNddK/23/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reload the entire page, you have to submit some information to the new page. To achieve this, you have to modify the links of your sub menu items, or set a cookie. On page load you have to parse these information (url or cookie), and apply this to your menu. You could also use some server side code to have a pre-rendered HTML where your sub menu is already open.

In this case jsFiddle is not a good helper to show you how it could work.

**EDIT:**

You could do the following (untested):

Give your top menu `<div>` a unique ID, i.e.

```
<div class="menutop" id="posts">
```

Add a hash to each URL of a sub item i.e.

```
<li><a href="/Post/New#posts">Add New</a></li>
```

Try this hash to open the menu

```
$(document.location.hash).click();
```

Comment: @DanielB can you help somehow?

Comment: Not good with js, where goes $(document.location.hash).click();part
can you explain me in few lines.
thx

Comment: this goes after all other JS in your `$(document).ready()` wrapper. Ive modified your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNddK/37/), but it wont work in fiddle, because the '#hash' will not be forwarded to the results iframe.

Comment: @DanielB Thx for your help.I did just like above, i think, but doesnt work :-(
What do you mean when you say results iframe?

any other way do accomplish this?

Comment: The comment to the iframe was only meant for the jsFiddle example. Try add a `alert(document.location.hash)` before the line with `.click()` and see if the value is correct.

Comment: @DanielB Alert box say #posts, but still nothing happens...:-(

Comment: Did you have set an id for the menu `<li><div class="menutop" id="posts"><a href="#">Posts</a>`? I missed that in my fiddle. Here an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/hNddK/39/). But remove the `|| '#posts'` in your code, its only for jsfiddle.

Comment: work great, thx

Is there easy way to highlight current active page through css, jquery?
thx, again

Comment: Well don't have to add the '#' if no name follows, because no menu has to be opened. on the other hand you can use `<a href="#" onclick="return false;">` but at you only need to add the '#name' to links that forward to another page.

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided works for me.

I forked your code and replaced the "Users \ Add new" option with "Users \ Google":

```
 <li><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/UKvva/

**EDIT**

After reading another answer I figured out that you want to keep the submenu open after leaving your page. In that case, my answer doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work? You should be able to place it just above the hitMe function.

```
var url = document.location.toString();
var url_array = url.split("/");
// get last item in array
var last = url_array[url_array.length-1];
$('a').each( function() {
    // if it matches
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(last) != -1) {
       $(this).parent().parent().show();
       $(this).css( { 'background': '#FFF4D2', 'color': '#333' });
    }
});
```

This should take the value of the link's path and open/style the list.

**EDIT**:

If you go to http://jsbin.com/urupo3/5/edit and click "Preview," you can see that the code does appear to work as the link `<a href="edit">` is highlighted and expanded.

Comment: Trying to implement this code.Im not good in js :-(.I guess that  code u gave me interfere with my main menu, also jquery navigation.How to target just this specific menu.And also when i insert code menu stops to working, Im not able to toogle(click) the menu items.Any idea?
thx